# Sigabrt Error NSPredicate Showing up in search bar xcode 4.5+

Tags: xcode, uisearchbar, nspredicate, sigabrt

Hi guys I'm currently having a problem with my search bar. When I run the project the search bar comes up and its all good, but when I actually type inside the search bar it returns a sigabrt error here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

This is my viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface CollegeViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar1;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITabBar *tabBar1;

@end
```

And this is my viewcontroller.m:

```
@interface CollegeViewController ()

@end

@implementation CollegeViewController {
NSArray *colleges;
NSArray *searchResults;

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"common_bg.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
self.tableView.contentInset = inset;
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.title = @"List of Colleges";
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
College *college1 = [College new];
college1.name = @"Harvard University";
college1.collegeName = @"Harvard University";
college1.rank = @"#1";
college1.imageFile = @"01.jpg";
college1.sizeofCollegeCampus = @"210 acres";
college1.tuition = @"$38,480";
college1.numberofStudents = @"27,392";
college1.address = @"Massachusetts Hall, Cambridge, MA 02138";
college1.acceptanceRate = @"5.9%";
college1.phoneNumber = @"(617) 495-1000";
college1.majorPrograms = @"Economics, Political Science and Government, Psychology,  English Language and Literature/Letters, and Social Sciences";
college1.website = @"www.harvard.edu/";
college1.isitIvyLeague = @"Yes";
college1.mascot = @"John Harvard";
college1.color = @"crimson";
college1.satScore = @"";
college1.actScore = @"";
college1.collegeNameCell = @"Harvard University";
college1.collegeRankCell = @"#1";
college1.collegePhotoCell = @"Harvard_Wreath_Logo_1.svg.png";


..............


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)
banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

searchResults = [colleges filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [searchResults count];

} else {
    return [colleges count];

}
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}


- (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
UIImage *background = nil;

if (rowIndex == 0) {
    background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_top.png"];
} else if (rowIndex == rowCount - 1) {
    background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bottom.png"];
} else {
    background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_middle.png"];
}

return background;
}   

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

}

    College *college = [colleges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *collegeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    collegeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:college.collegePhotoCell];

    UILabel *CollegeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    CollegeNameLabel.text = college.collegeNameCell;

    UILabel *CollegeRankLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    CollegeRankLabel.text = college.collegeRankCell;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        College *college = [colleges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImageView *collegeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        collegeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:college.collegePhotoCell];

        UILabel *CollegeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        CollegeNameLabel.text = college.collegeNameCell;

        UILabel *CollegeRankLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        CollegeRankLabel.text = college.collegeRankCell;
    } else {

        College *college = [colleges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImageView *collegeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        collegeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:college.collegePhotoCell];

        UILabel *CollegeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        CollegeNameLabel.text = college.collegeNameCell;

        UILabel *CollegeRankLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        CollegeRankLabel.text = college.collegeRankCell;

    }


    // Assign our own background image for the cell
    UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    cellBackgroundView.image = background;
    cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;




// Display college in the table cell

return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCollegeDetail"]) {
    CollegeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.college = [colleges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }

}



@end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably paste the error aswell for best chance of help.